# Kubuntu 22.04 stuck at 'running /scripts/init-premount' with apparent nvidia driver module failures

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu

I have a Kubuntu 22.04 + Windows 11 dual boot setup. It seems after I upgraded the Nvidia drivers and enrolled some keys for the secure boot verification, booting in the 5.15.73 kernel version (default) the boot screen gets stuck after loading module output. Apparently, `nvidia-drm`, `nvidia-modeset` has some issues.

[image: Kubuntu boot output]
Note that I can boot in an earlier kernel in grub (`5.15.72`) successfully, but `nvidia-smi` raises kernel module/driver mismatch issues.

Based on reading related issues, it seems the nvidia driver upgrade process is the problem, don't recall what exactly the steps were. Let me know and I will add extra info.

Attached some info about the current system (`5.15.72`):

```
> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  530.41.03  Thu Mar 16 19:48:20 UTC 2023
GCC version:  gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

> lspci | grep -i nvidia

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)


> uname -m && cat /etc/*release

x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy


> gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


> uname -r

5.15.0-72-generic

> dpkg -l | grep nvidia

iU  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                          535.43.02-0ubuntu0~gpu22.04.2               all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-515:amd64                   515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-530:amd64                   530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                  amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
iU  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
iU  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                    535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
iU  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                    535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
iU  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
iU  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                    535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
iU  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
iU  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
iU  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
iU  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                       535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
iF  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                        535.43.02-0ubuntu0~gpu22.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
iU  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                         535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-43-generic    5.15.0-43.46+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-43
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-60-generic    5.15.0-60.66                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-60
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-67-generic    5.15.0-67.74                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-67
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-69-generic    5.15.0-69.76+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-69
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-70-generic    5.15.0-70.77+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-70
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-71-generic    5.15.0-71.78                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-71
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-530-5.15.0-72-generic    5.15.0-72.79                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-72
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-530-5.15.0-73-generic    5.15.0-73.80                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-73
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-43-generic    5.15.0-43.46+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-43 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-60-generic    5.15.0-60.66                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-60 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-67-generic    5.15.0-67.74                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-67 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-69-generic    5.15.0-69.76+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-69 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-70-generic    5.15.0-70.77+1                              amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-70 (objects)
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-71-generic    5.15.0-71.78                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-71 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-530-5.15.0-72-generic    5.15.0-72.79                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-72 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-530-5.15.0-73-generic    5.15.0-73.80                                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-73 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-72-generic     5.15.0-72.79                                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-72-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-73-generic     5.15.0-73.80                                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-73-generic
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-515                      515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-530                      530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
iU  nvidia-compute-utils-535                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-530                               530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                  amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
iU  nvidia-dkms-535-open                          535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
iU  nvidia-driver-535-open                        535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage
iU  nvidia-firmware-535-535.54.03                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-515                      515.105.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-530                      530.41.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                  amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
iU  nvidia-kernel-common-535                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
iU  nvidia-kernel-source-535-open                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.17.1                                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               510.47.03-0ubuntu1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
iU  nvidia-utils-535                              535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                       0.18.2                                      all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
iU  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

```
   > lsmod | grep nvidia  
    nvidia_drm             77824  1
    nvidia_modeset       1273856  1 nvidia_drm
    nvidia              55738368  1 nvidia_modeset
    drm_kms_helper        311296  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
    drm                   622592  30 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm
```

Is it a good idea to purge and uninstall nvidia drivers and revert to the earlier version?